# Remove Date Ambiguity

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form that builds a filter.

I have two textboxes that are used as the start and end date for the filter. They have format `Short Date`

The vba code is as follows:

```
Dim fdate4 As Date
Dim fdate5 As Date


fdate4 = Format(txtStart, "yyyy/mm/dd", vbMonday, vbFirstJan1)
fdate5 = Format(txtFinish, "yyyy/mm/dd", vbMonday, vbFirstJan1)
```

When I try filter by 1 Oct - 31 Dec and debug.print the form filter I see:

```
[DutyDate] BETWEEN #01/10/2015# AND #31/12/2015#
```

However, it includes dates from January. Is this to do with the formatting on the form itself or the filter string.

I have tried using `CDate` along with other formats `dd/\mm/\yyyy` however that all give the same result.

Comment: I think you should `Dim fdate4 As String`, or the `Format()` will have no effect - date variables don't have a format.

Comment: Please post more of your code. This code cannot be the complete one.

Comment: @George: Missing lines added to answer.

Comment: @Gustav Ah I understand, you completely missed these lines  - then of course it couldn't work! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use something like this as the last parameters of Format are for weeks only and "/" alone is not a slash but the (localized) date separator:

```
Dim fdate4 As String
Dim fdate5 As String

fdate4 = Format(txtStart, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")
fdate5 = Format(txtFinish, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")
```

The missing lines for George:

```
Me.Filter = "[DutyDate] BETWEEN #" & fdate4 & "# AND #" & fdate5 & "#"
Me.FilterOn = True
```